# Why does my Gmail address appear as my handle in Android Market reviews?

Tags: android, gmail, google-play

I am really frustrated that my Gmail address appears as my handle in Android Market reviews. As a result I really can't review apps because I don't want to get spammed.

How do I change my handle? I cannot find this setting anywhere. :(

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably does not belong on Stack Overflow. Android stack exchange is likely more appropriate. However, the answer is Market uses your "nickname" from your google account. If you do not have a nickname set then it will take your first name. I imagine if you don't have that set it uses your full email. Either way you can change it with these instructions: 
http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=70206#

Click nickname once you get there. It'll show you how to find that setting in your account

Comment: I was afraid I was posting in the wrong forum but thanks for answering anyway. It worked!